# Independent paired t-test -> Mann Whitney U

Tags: t-test, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test

Just a quick introduction, I'm rubbish at stats.
I asked a question before which was very well answered but I have since modified the experiment in a way that confuses me as to which test I should use.

So in the previous question we finished concluding that an independent t-test would be suffice as I am comparing the effect of irradiation on each leaf so, one half would be the control or the "before", and the irradiated half would be the "after" treatment. Well, I got my results, but I didn't map out which irradiated half went with what control as it was very difficult to keep track so I ended up with a jumbled set of controls to a jumbled set of irradiated.

So I made the following changes to my experiment:

1) Instead of having 5 circles per half of leaf, I instead opted for just 1. This meant it was quicker to get results as things like overlapping circles reducing light intake for the leaf discs on bottom didn't happen. So I would initially cut all my leaves in half. take one sample from one half, and whilst waiting for photosynthesis to take place I would irradiate the other halve(s), which brings me on to my second change..

2) I did 3 syringes at the same time instead of just 1 quadrupling my speed. (That's what I meant when I said I did four at the same time), so 4 control, whilst waiting, irradiate other halves of leaves for a minute and switch once photosynthesis finished, then switch again to another batch of 4 leaves and repeat. I ended up with 16 results either side

Comment: If you have jumbled control and treatment labels, nothing can rescue it. On your last sentence - standard deviation of *what*?

Comment: Oh damn :L Ok, well I'll explain what I did in further detail. So I have to work out "If applicable" things like mean and Standard Deviation. So can I do that with my results? All my values are above 0 (since I'm using a stopwatch to measure). Again, so that means I can't do a statistical test? Surely if I've got n number of results for non-irradiated with an equal n number of control, there can be another test I can do??

Comment: I didn't really follow your explanation in further detail, sorry, perhaps you can explain in more detail in an edit to your question. Where you say - "*surely if I've got n number of results for non-irradiated with an equal n number of control*" - you can compare them only if you know which is which. It's possible I misunderstood something, I suppose. Do you have some of each group where you do know which treatment group they're from?

Comment: Ohh yes yes, I 100% know which is control and which is irradiated. It's just, for my test I would have had to compare a before and after for EACH INDIVIDUAl leaf (paired t-test). But I didn't keep track of which control/irradited was for which leaf (as I did 4 at a time). So what's a broad statistical test I could use to compare the difference between the control and irradiated (Again I can explain if it's not clear. It is difficult to describe, sorry).

Comment: Oh, you mean you just lost the pairing? Then you do a two-sample test instead of a paired. You'll lose some power but all is not lost. I can probably give an answer now. Still not clear about computing standard deviation *from* a Mann-Whitney. Why not compute them from the samples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've lost the information that would let you identify the inherent pairing in your data. This is unfortunate and will likely cost you power, but you can still do a test.

With the loss of pairing, you're in a two-sample situation.

You seem to suggest you're thinking of a Mann-Whitney test. That may well be suitable depending on the specific hypothesis you're interested in testing and the specific additional assumptions you may be willing to make.

If you're willing to assume identical shapes apart from possible location shift, you can use a Mann-Whitney to test means, for example. If you want a more general location test, you don't necessarily need to assume identical shape. It sounds like your data are potentially fairly discrete - are you likely to have lots of ties?

Another possibility is - especially with such small samples - to consider a permutation test of whatever is quantity is of interest.

Comment: The link I gave you was a little wrong. So I initially was going to do the technical replicates thing, but I realised that would take a long long time. So instead, I made the following changes:

Comment: Perhaps you should edit the information into your question.

Comment: I think I've lost you >.<

Comment: Thanks for the extra info. What would be the null and alternative hypothesis you'd be most interested in testing - in plain words rather than formal notation. (Are you able to put up the data, by the way?) There are several further questions in my partial answer.

Comment: The alternative is very general - do you want to reject the null if one sample is more variable than the other? Or are you really trying to find out if it maybe increases or decreases? Which values are those 16?

Comment: Assuming you only care about a location difference, your data would be fine to use either a t-test or a Mann-Whitney (with adjustment for ties), or indeed a permutation test; the assumptions don't look like a big issue for any of them. None of your results will be significant, however (I didn't test it; you can tell by looking).

Comment: That's a lot of stuff being asked for... Briefly - what "*..."smallest U-value of 116.5" and "a critical value of U of 75*" means *exactly* depends on the specific definition of U being used. In this case it seems that it's taking the sum of the ranks in first sample minus the minimum possible sum of ranks, or perhaps (given the 'smallest' phrasing) it computes that for both samples and takes the smaller. You don't have a p-value of 0.05. A t-value is the value of a t-statistic, such as in a [two-sample t-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-test#Independent_two-sample_t-test).

Comment: I can't guess all of what you are seeing. Telling you the value of the test statistic and the critical values is not "just there to confuse you". Personally, I'd state at least the p-value (if your software is giving that). Failing that, I'd state a rejection rule in terms of a 5% critical value (for a 5% test - with the rejection rule stated after the hypotheses but before the observed value of the statistic). As for what you're "supposed" to do, that would depend on your audience - I am no mindreader as to what they expect from you.

Comment: `If you're willing to assume identical shapes [i.e. the populations' shapes are identical], you can use a Mann-Whitney to test means` Do you insist on means? Why not medians? (knowing that _samples_ shapes won't be exactly identical and can be skewed, but ranking data erases any remembrance of the means)

Comment: @ttnphns I don't know whether the OP insists on means or not, but *if* identical shapes (identical distribution apart from location shift\*) are assumed, *then* a rank test like a Mann-Whitney is not only completely valid as a test for difference in means, it *can even provide a consistent estimator of that location shift*. The fact that the rank transformation *itself* doesn't 'remember' where the mean is, is beside the point being made here. [\* with the proviso that if you're testing means, the common distribution is one whose mean exists, and perhaps some additional regularity conditions]

Comment: Yes, I agree, _if_ by "equal shape" to mean `identical distribution apart from ... shift` Then of course, the test is just the test of that shift (and hence of any quantile, including that one corresponding to mean).